# Счетчик textarea

Tags: textarea, javascript

Помогите, нужен счетчик `textarea`, как в твиттере, чтобы разрешал писать дальше но уходил в минус, можно это исправить:

```
function length_check(len_max, field_id, counter_id) {
    var len_current = document.getElementById(field_id).value.length;
    var rest = len_max - len_current;
    if (len_current > len_max )
    {   document.getElementById(field_id).value =
        document.getElementById(field_id).value.substr (0, len_max);
        if (rest > len_max) { rest = len_max;}
        document.getElementById(counter_id).firstChild.data = rest;
        }
    else
    {   document.getElementById(counter_id).firstChild.data = rest; }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Видите, по какой ветке идёт код, когда длина превышает максимум? Видите, что делает скрипт? Тогда почему вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не принципиально важно, то вот [набросал вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ8F9/2/) на jQuery.

Comment: Наверное, `if(chars > limit)`? Ноль должен быть всё ещё зелёным. А можно ещё сделать, чтобы реагировало на right click -> paste?

Comment: ноль как раз должен быть красным, спасибо. воспользуюсь вашим вариантом

Answer (score 1):

Столько сложностей, чтобы просто посчитать разницу А и Б?

```
max = 100; // максимально допустимое значение
text_len = textarea.value.length; // на данный момент
count = max - text_len; // осталось
span_element.innerText = count;
span_element.style.color = (count < 0 ? 'red' : 'green');
```

Всё. Положить в функцию и навесить на onchange / onkeydown / ...